# -bash: jps: command not found (hadoop)

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm, environment-variables

Im trying to install hadoop. When I execute the `start-all.sh` I got no errors.

But then to test if all components weres started Im using the command `jps`, but appears always

```
-bash: jps: command not found
```

I already configure some variables in .bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin
```

Also if I try to acess:localhost:50060/jobtracker.jsp I got an error:

```
Problem acessing /jobtracker.jsp Reason: /jobtracker.jsp
```

Do you understand why its not working?

Comment: have you tried launching jps using the absolute location? for example <install-dir>/bin/jps

Comment: have you installed java? I guess yes, on the $JAVA_HOME path, but just checking... :) type `java -version` to be sure

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried to launch jps inside hadoop/bin directory, but I get t/he same error. And yes I have java installed.

Comment: Jps is a Java utility rather than Hadoop utility. It should be inside $JAVA_HOME/bin directory. And from your $JAVA_HOME path I guess you have only JRE installed and JRE does not contain JPS tool. You should install JDK to use it.

Comment: Thanks also, I tried use jsp inside java bin directory but same error. And I installed the jdk version.